# How can I include a file from a child theme

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a file in my child theme root directory named image-svg.php

The in another file under childthemename/page-templates/filexample.php

I want to include  image-svg.php

I tried different ways but the file does no get included:

```
<?php get_template_part('africa-map-svg.php'); ?>
<?php include('africa-map-svg.php'); ?>
```

How can I include this file ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [get_template_directory](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_directory/) to retrieve the directory of the current theme.

```
<?php require get_template_directory().'/africa-map-svg.php'; ?>
```

Comment: It breaks the site

Comment: No error. the site just breaks.
Any html after this code gets removed.

Comment: @deSousa You might want to enable errors with `ini_set('display_errors, true);` to see the error that is being thrown there. Is your active theme the child theme where the SVG is located at?

Answer (score 0):

You can use following function to include any file. `get_theme_file_uri()`

please try this

```
<?php require_once (get_theme_file_uri('/africa-map-svg.php')); ?>
```